# Store values from an array of JSON objects in SQL DB using Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, api, azure-data-factory

I am trying to teach myself Azure Data Factory and am attempting some "simple" API exercises.

I successfully loaded data from an API call into a SQL database using the `copy data` activity and adding the simple mapping.

[image: Mapping]

However, this was for an API call that returned a single JSON object as below.

```
{
    "id": "tt0110413",
    "title": "Léon: The Professional",
    "year": "1994",
    "releaseDate": "1994-11-18",
    "runtimeMins": "110",
    "plot": "12-year-old Mathilda is reluctantly taken in by Léon...",
    "imDbRating":"8.5"
}
```

I would like to progress this to be able to handle an array of JSON objects as below.

```
{
    "items":
    [
        {
            "id": "tt0111161",
            "title": "The Shawshank Redemption"
        },
        {
            "id": "tt0068646",
            "title": "The Godfather"
        },
        {
            "id": "tt0468569",
            "title": "The Dark Knight"
        }
    ],
    "errorMessage": ""
}
```

I have naively thought this would be a simple matter pointing the `copy data` activity at the new JSON and updating the mapping as required.

[image: Mapping 2]

However I now receive the following error:

> Data type of column 'id' can't be inferred from 1st row of data,
> please specify its data type in mappings of copy activity or structure
> of DataSet

Would someone be able to advise on how I change the mapping to handle this, or if in fact this is entirely the wrong approach.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have a one level array, this shouldn't be hard. You will need to use a collection reference, and in your example that would be "items".

[image: Collection Reference]

Unfortunately, ADF is very limited on the complexity of collections/arrays in JSON and can only handle a single collection reference. I have found it personally easier to do a WEB API call instead of a copy activity and push that JSON text to a Stored Procedure.

From there you can pretty easily shred the JSON however you would like. Here is an example of what a pretty simple Stored Proc would look like that takes the JSON Output:

```
ALTER Procedure [Log].[PopulatePowerBIGroups] (
@json NVARCHAR(MAX))
as
select @json j
;
insert into Log.PowerBI_GroupsTmp
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.id' ) AS groupID,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.isReadOnly' ) AS isReadOnly,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.isOnDedicatedCapacity' ) AS isOnDedicatedCapacity,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.capacityId' ) AS capacityId,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.capacityMigrationStatus' ) AS capacityMigrationStatus,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.description' ) AS description,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.type' ) AS type,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.state' ) AS state,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.name' ) AS groupName,
    Stag.CSTReturnDate(getdate()) as ETL_UpdateTimestamp
FROM OPENJSON( @json ) j
where JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.name' ) not like 'DUMMY%'
and JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.state' ) = 'Active'
```

But of course for very simple web output, a Copy Data activity will work just fine!

Comment: Thats done the trick! Thanks!